# Compile cdylib with different calling conventions

Tags: rust

I need to compile a cdylib with extern functions with the cdecl and stdcall calling conventions on windows.

I have some functions declarations like this:

```
pub extern "C" fn foo() -> {}.
```

and I would like to conditionally compile it with:

```
pub extern "stdcall" fn foo() -> {}.
```

So I am looking for the possibility to write:

```
pub extern fn foo() -> {}
```

and set the calling convention globally or something like this:

```
#[mymacro]
pub fn foo() -> {}
```

I would prefer the latter, because I would introduce a crate feature and 
call cargo build --features=stdcall.